# Minimum of a function -approximate value

Tags: calculus, functions

Consider the function below:

$f(x)=\frac{x}{1-\left(1-a^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}}$, $x\geq 1$.

We also have that $0<a<<1$, $d>>1$.

By plotting on Matlab, I can clearly see that this function has an absolute minimum.
However, I am not able to calculate analytically this minimum. I tried via derivation, but the resulting expression has not straightforward zeros.

I don't necessarily need the exact value of the minimum, an approximate value would also be fine.

Anyone can help or suggest a strategy?

Answer (score 0):

For a very tidy approximation, take $\displaystyle x=\frac{1}{\log_{a}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$. To derive this, first observe that $f$ should attain its minimum at the zero of its derivative. But as $f=\frac{u}{v}$ is a quotient, its derivative $f'=\frac{vu'-uv'}{v^2}$ will be zero only if its numerator is. Hence, compute $vu'-uv'$, where $u=x$ and $v=1-\left(1-a^{1/x}\right)^{1/d}$, recalling that since $\left(e^{f(x)}\right)'=f'(x)e^{f(x)}$ and $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$, we must have $\left(a^{1/x}\right)'=-x^{-2}\ln\left(a\right)a^{\frac{1}{x}}$.

We should find

$$vu'-uv' = 1-\left(1-a^{1/x}\right)^{1/d }+\frac{\ln\left(a\right)a^{1/x}}{dx}\left(1-a^{1/x}\right)^{1/d -1}\quad (=0)$$

This seems unappealing but can be swiftly reduced by eliminating the variable $d$ through some slick manipulations. Substitute $h=1/d$ such that for large $d$, we have $h\to0$, and divide through by $h$.

$$-\frac{\left(1-a^{1/x}\right)^{h}-1}{h}+\frac{\ln\left(a\right)a^{1/x}}{x}\left(1-a^{1/x}\right)^{h -1}=0$$

But now recognize the leftmost term as the limit definition of the natural logarithm! $\frac{a^h-1}{h}\to \ln a$. (Equivalently, observe that [treating $x$ as a constant] the fraction on the left is a difference quotient of the function $g(t)=(1-a^{1/x})^t$, explicitly $\frac{g(0+h)-g(0)}{h}\to g'(0)$.) The occurrence of $h$ in the rightmost term can be treated with direct substitution. Hence, in the limit for large $d$, we have

$$-\ln\left(1-a^{1/x}\right)+\frac{\ln\left(a\right)a^{1/x}}{x}\left(1-a^{1/x}\right)^{-1}=0
\\
w\ln\left(w\right)-\left(1-w\right)\ln\left(1-w\right)=0$$

where in the second line, we substitute $w=a^{1/x}$. This last expression gives exactly three zeros, $w=0,\frac12,1$, of which the second is our desired root. Hence, $a^{1/x}=\frac12$ so $x=\frac{1}{\log_{a}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful indeed. I presume it is not straightforward to find a solution that depends on $d$ also, i.e. for generic $d$, not necessarily large, right?

Comment: I can see from matlab plots that the expression you provided approximates well the minimum of $f(x)$, even for moderately large $d$. My confusion come from the fact that, the derivation above is obtained for $d \to \infty$... But if we apply the same limit to $f(x)$, we obtain $\infty$ as well... Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Garbt We are taking $d$ to infinity, yes, but the convergence of the function is sufficiently fast, and the function changes fairly little when $d$ is increased, so the approximation is good, even for fairly small $d$. Compare this with the convergence of the function $1/x$ to zero. Whether we have fairly large $x$, as in $\frac1{1000}=0.001$, or very large $x$, as in $\frac1{1\,000\,000}=0.000\,001$, what we get is hardly different from zero (the limit as $x\to\infty$). The convergence is fast enough that we can consider any *reasonably* large input to be similar to the limit at infinity.

Comment: As to whether there is a good approximation that incorporates $d$ as a variable as well, there might be. I've not come up with one, however.